# Python nested for loops output unpredictable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code which I wrote for the [project Euler question #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4):

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
def foo():
for x in xrange (999,100,-1):
    for y in xrange (999,100,-1):
        product= (x*y)
        if str(product)== str(product)[::-1]:
            print product
foo()
```

This code generates a continuous output of all palindromes since i have omitted a break. However the output is as follows:

```
580085
514415
906609
119911
282282
141141
853358
650056
601106
..
..
```

I can't figure out why the largest number doesn't print out first. A similar code in C gives the largest number on the very top. Is there something about Python `for` loops I'm missing?

Comment: You should look more closely at what `x` and `y` values are producing those products...

Comment: Try `print x,y,product` in place of `print product`, and see what you notice.

Comment: Since there is no `xrange` in C I'm curious what the "similar code in C" looks like.

Comment: If you want your palindromes sorted, store them in a list during the for loops, then sort and print them a the end.

Comment: I hope you noticed that your output contains each palindrome twice. And are you sure that you want to use [Python 2](https://pythonclock.org/) instead of Python 3 as a beginner?

Comment: @KlausD. If you're interested, it's in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer look at the values producing the product would've answered your question. The first number, `580085` is produced by `x = 995` and `y = 583`. Similarly, the third product `906609` is produced by `x = 993` and `y = 913`. The loops are iterating in reverse as they should.

It just so happens that the largest palindromes need not necessarily be generated by the largest multiplicands.

If you want to find the largest palindrome, convert this function to a generator, and call `max` on it. Furthermore, as pointed out in the comments, you're iterating over each pair of numbers twice, once as an x-y pair, and another as a y-x pair. Modify your second loop slightly so you don't have to perform those redundant computations. `y` should decrease down till `x`, not `100`.

```
def foo(l, u):
    for x in xrange(u, l, -1):
        for y in xrange(u, x - 1, -1):
            v = x * y
            if str(v) == str(v)[::-1]:
                yield v
```

Call it as such:

```
>>> max(foo(100, 999))
906609
```

For python-3.x, change `xrange` to `range`.

---

I was also curious as to what you meant when you were talking about C code giving you your expected output. So I wrote a little code to test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[42];

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397607/4909087
int is_palindrome(char const* s)
{
   int len = strlen(s);
   if ( len == 0 ) // An empty string a palindrome
   {
      return 1;
   }

   int i = 0;
   int j = len-1;
   for ( ; i < j; ++i, --j )
   {
      if ( s[i] != s[j] )
      {
         // the string is not a palindrome.
         return 0;
      }
   }

   // If we don't return from inside the for loop,
   // the string is a palindrome.
   return 1;
}


int main(){    
    int x, y; 
    for (x = 999; x >= 100; x--)
        for (y = 999; y >= 100; y--) 
        {
            sprintf(buf, "%d", x * y);
            if(is_palindrome(buf)){
                printf("%d\n", x * y);
            }    
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this returns:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out

580085
514415
906609
119911
282282
141141
853358
650056
601106
592295
543345
485584
...
```

Which are exactly the same numbers you get with your python program. Note that this is still inefficient, the right way to do this would be to change the inner loop's definition to `for (y = 999; y >= x; y--)`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick in this is that the loops are iterated from inner loop to outer loop. First the inner is iterated with value of 999 for the outer loop then the inner loop is iterated for a value of 998 for the outer loop.

The resulting products are not sorted in decending order since (e.g. 995 * 583  < 993 * 913 but the first product is calculated earlier since x (first element of the product) is higher (outer loop)).

Answer (score 0):

While there are better answers already, just posting how the output is generated.
I just modified the code for Py3. As others explained, the behaviour is normal. Since the outer loop's x value will reduce by 1, only when the inner loop's y hit 100 hence the output you see is not in descending order.

```
for x in range(999,100,-1):
    for y in range(999,100,-1):
        product= (x*y)
        if str(product)== str(product)[::-1]:
            print('x is ' + str(x) + '; y is ' + str(y))
            print(product)
```

Output:

```
x is 995; y is 583
580085
x is 995; y is 517
514415
x is 993; y is 913
906609
x is 991; y is 121
119911
x is 987; y is 286
282282
x is 987; y is 143
141141
x is 982; y is 869
853358
x is 979; y is 664
650056
x is 979; y is 614
601106
x is 979; y is 605
592295
x is 979; y is 555
543345
x is 979; y is 496
485584
x is 979; y is 446
436634
x is 979; y is 387
378873
x is 979; y is 337
329923
x is 978; y is 418
408804
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code that will print values from highest to lowest as you are seeking.

It is a bit more optimal as it avoids redundant multiplications, and filters out duplicates that can happen anyway.  (e.g. 111*9 == 333*3 == 999).

I did this in Python 3.  You might need to import the Set module manually for Python 2.

```
def foo():
    result = set()
    for x in range (999,1,-1):
        for y in range (999,x,-1):
            product= (x*y)
            if str(product)== str(product)[::-1]:
                result.add(x*y)
    result = list(result)
    result = sorted(result,reverse=True)
    for i in result:
         print(i)
foo()
```